# Match an expression with at least a prefix and/or a postfix without repeating the expressions

Tags: regex, python-3.6, simplify

Let's say

```
((pre)(expr)(post)?|(pre)?(expr)(post))
```

This is meant to match expr with at least a prefix or a postfix or both but not with neither.

```
preexpr - OK
exprpost - OK
preexprpost - OK
expr - BAD
```

This example is using letters, but all three sub-expressions could be any valid regex, not just letters.

Is there a way of writing an equivalent regex with each expression appearing only once? I'm trying to improve readability.

Right now I know I can remove the second occurrence of `pre`:

```
((pre)(expr)(post)?|(expr)(post))
```

but I'm wondering if it can still be reduced.

Thank you

Comment: Build a pattern dynamically from blocks that you will declare once. With [PyPi regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/), you can use "branch reset".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*YES* - This is what conditional constructs `(?(n)yes regex|no regex)` are made for.

In my opinion, the only value for conditionals are to pass or fail
the match based on something that *did* or *did not* match.

In this case, the below regex is checking if either optional groups 1 or 3 matched.
In reality, 'pre' and 'post' can be humungous sub-expressions
(but be careful of backtracking pitfalls).

This saves duplicity of sub-expressions.

https://regex101.com/r/QdhRn2/1

`(pre)?(expr)(post)?(?(1)|(?(3)|(?!)))`

Explained

```
 ( pre )?                      # (1), Optional 'pre'
 ( expr )                      # (2), Required 'exp'
 ( post )?                     # (3), Optional 'post'
                               # Post mortum
 (?(1)                         # Did group 1 match ?
   |  (?(3)                         # No, then did group 3 match ?
        |  (?!)                          # No.  Fail the whole thing
      )
 )
 # Here, at least group 1 or 3 matched, possibly both
```

[Explained *Verbose*](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 ( pre )?                      # (1), Optional 'pre'
 ( expr )                      # (2), Required 'exp'
 ( post )?                     # (3), Optional 'post'
                               # Post mortum
 (?(1)                         # Did group 1 match ?
                                    # Yes, all done
   |                              # or,
      (?(3)                         # No, then did group 3 match ?
                                         # Yes, all done
        |                              # or,
           (?!)                          # No.  Fail the whole thing
      )
 )
 # Here, at least group 1 or 3 matched, possibly both
```